# Is this true that this equation has three possible roots?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is this true that this equation

[image]

has three solutions (provided $f(x)$, $g(x)$ are defined):

$f(x) = 0 $, provided $g(x)$ is defined, or

$g(x) =0 $, provided $f(x)$ is defined, or

$f(x)+g(x)=0 $, provided $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are defined (in the equation with square roots)

How to prove it strictly?

Comment: The argument $x$ is of little use.

Comment: Are you assuming that $f$ and $g$ are real and $\sqrt[3]{\,}$ is a function $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Raise to the third power to get

$$f+3\sqrt[3]{f^2g}+3\sqrt[3]{fg^2}+g=f+g.$$

After simplification, this is equivalent to

$$f^2g=-fg^2$$

or

$$f=0\lor g=0\lor f+g=0.$$

Comment: $f^2g=-fg^2$ => $f^2g+fg^2 = 0$ => $f*g*(f+g)=0$